# Entity `uuid`, `chaged`, `created` not populating on creation

Tags: 8, entities

I have a series of entities that are all implemented through inheritance.  They are described below.  But the crux of the problem is that when I create a new instance of an entity: `$dog = new Dog([], 'dog')->save();` I get a MySQL constraint error saying that `uuid cannot be null`.

Here is how I have the classes constructed.  The installation of these is correct, so it's not a problem with that.  I'm not sure if it's a problem with the plugin definition (though I've tried starting from scratch and using the d8 documentation with no success) or the way my fields are defined/constructed:

**BaseAnimal Entity**:

```
abstract class BaseAnimal extends ContentEntityBase implements BaseAnimalInterface {
  use EntityChangedTrait;
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * When a new entity instance is added, set the user_id entity reference to
   * the current user as the creator of the instance.
   */
  public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage_controller, array &$values) {
    parent::preCreate($storage_controller, $values);
    $values += array('user_id' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),);
  }
 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function getCreatedTime() {
    return $this->get('created')->value;
  }
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
  public function getChangedTime() {
    return $this->get('changed')->value;
  }
 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function setChangedTime($timestamp) {
    $this->set('changed', $timestamp);
    return $this;
  }
 /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  *
  * Define the field properties here.
  *
  * Field name, type and size determine the table structure.
  *
  * In addition, we can define how the field and its content can be manipulated
  * in the GUI. The behaviour of the widgets used can be determined here.
  */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    // I've tried putting $fields['uuid'], $fields['changed'], 
    // $fields['created'], and $fields['id'] here but it didn't work

    // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
    $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('ID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The ID of the entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    // Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
    $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
      ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
      ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the entity.'))
      ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Created'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));
    return $fields;   
  }

}
```

**BaseAnimalInterface**:

```
public interface BaseAnimalInteraface extends ContentEntityInterface, EntityChangedInterface {}
```

**Dog Entity**:

```
/**
 * Defines the dog entity class.
 *
 * @ingroup module_name
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "dog",
 *   label = @Translation("Dog"),
 *   label_collection = @Translation("Dog"),
 *   label_singular = @Translation("dog"),
 *   label_plural = @Translation("dogs"),
 *   label_count = //omitted for brevity
 *   handlers = { [omitted for brevity],
 *     "form" = { [omitted for brevity] },},
 *   base_table = "dog",
 *   data_table = "dog_data",
 *   fieldable = TRUE,
 *   translatable = FALSE,
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "name" = "name",
 *   },
 *   common_reference_target = TRUE,
 *   links = { [omitted for brevity] },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "entity_type.dog.settings",
 * )
 */
class Dog extends BaseAnimal implements DogInterface {
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    *
    * When a new entity instance is added, set the user_id entity reference to
    * the current user as the creator of the instance.
    */
    public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage_controller, array &$values) {
      parent::preCreate($storage_controller, $values);
      $values += array(
        'user_id' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
      );
    }
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    *
    * Define the field properties here.
    *
    * Field name, type and size determine the table structure.
    *
    * In addition, we can define how the field and its content can be manipulated
    * in the GUI. The behaviour of the widgets used can be determined here.
    */
    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
     $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
     // custom fields that don't mutate the id, uuid, changed, or created fields.
     // I've also tried adding the id, uuid, changed, created fields here to no avail.
     // omitted additional fields for brevity.

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

**DogInterface**:

```
interface DogInterface extends BaseAnimalInterface {}
```

And so the problem comes when I try to:

```
$dog = new Dog([/* Omitted for brevity */], 'dog');
$dog->save();
```

Once I run the save function the database spits out a constraint violation stating that `uuid` cannot be `null`.

Comment: tl;dr, (Dog::create($values))->save()

Comment: ...#smh.  Did I miss something reading the documentation?  All the documentation I read says to use the `new Entity()` instance way.  And I don't recall every seeing anywhere to use the `(Entity::create())` way.  Also, could you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Not sure where you have been reading that you can do new Entity(). You can not. $storage->create() or as a shortcut, Entity::create() is the only way to create an entity object.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing Symfony docs and Drupal docs? Although I don't know if there are "entities" in Symfony anyway :D

Comment: It is most likely me being exhausted while I develop and cannot read correctly.